# python draw a graph with custom text

Tags: python, python-3.x, d3.js, graph, draw

I looking for something that could help to draw a custom information like a graph along with custom text like on the following image.

[image]

All popular graph drawing tools are just graph drawing tool but I need something that can draw text at some location, a graph at some location, I don't need fancy graph, just simple one like on the picture.

D3 in javascript are actually doing something similar, however I am not sure this is the best solution for Python. Then I need to export it to png file.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) to do this - it will allow for very flexible control of text.

As an example of what you've asked for, try this script ([based on this gallery example](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)

plt.figure(1)
sub = plt.subplot(121)

# Add 'Text' entries
sub.text(x=0.1, y=1, s="Text 1")
sub.text(x=0, y=.5, s="Text 2")
sub.text(x=0.2, y=.25, s="Text 3")
sub.text(x=0.15, y=0, s="Text 4")
sub.axis('off')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(t1, np.cos(2*np.pi*t1), 'r--')
plt.show()
```

Note: I didn't edit the font or size at all. See [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) for more info on text control.

Alternatively, you add text with the (x, y) coordinates outside of the chart's axes and skip adding a subplot. Like this:
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)

plt.figure(1)

plt.plot(t1, np.cos(2*np.pi*t1), 'r--')
plt.text(x=-5, y=.5, s="Way over here")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is great for all that. Not clear what you mean by fancy. If you're dealing with dates on the x-axis, you could use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(np.random.random(100))
plt.text(120,0.5,'Text1')
plt.text(120,0.3,'Text2',fontdict={'size':15})
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.show()
```